# Styling input and span as button class, slight difference

Tags: html, css

I want to make all buttons on my website follow a flat button class, input buttons or span buttons should be exactly the same.

I have applied the same class, removing border, adding padding, etc.. but, the buttons using the   element appear slightly bigger than the ones using the form button.

Why is that? What other css property could I edit to make them look the same (aside from having a preset height for all of them?)

This is my button class:

```
.button{
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 15px;    
    line-height: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raphadko/f3293yeL/

Comment: [**Spans are not buttons :)**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: is it a bad practice to use clickable spans as buttons? what should I use instead?

Comment: The linked article is pretty clear. **"The first thing to be aware of is that a SPAN should never be used as a button"** If it's going to be used as an action trigger, use an actual button. There's no specific reason to use a span at all. - http://jsfiddle.net/f3293yeL/1/

Comment: I see, thanks man! I didn't see it was a link, i guess this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be to wrap the buttons inside the spans. That way, you'll total control of the button positioning. Do not use them as button inside a form!

```css
span > .button {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <span>
       <input type="submit" class="button" value="Button1" />
        </span>
  
  <span>
       <input type="submit" class="button" value="Button2" />
        </span>
  
  <span>
       <input type="submit" class="button" value="Button3" />
        </span>
    
</form>
```

**Note:** The spans can help you position the element easily but its not advisable to use it as button when a form is concerned.